# Debian installer, how to use 2 ssd's with encryption

Tags: debian, installation

I have a new notebook which has 2 ssd's, but i'n not able to configure the disklayout with the debian installer the way i want it.

Ssd 2 has 1 TB and should be used as /home, but encrypted.

Ssd 1 has 128 GB and should be used as /, /boot and swap.

As the notebook has 8GB RAM, the swap space should also be 8GB. Boot might have 3GB, which I think is enough, right? The rest would be /.
I startet several tries debian installer to accive this, but i failed. Once the installer told me a "EFI partition" is also needed, for what?
I also look for a howto/doku/..., but i haven't found one, which fits to my setup.

Answer (score -1):

Today I solved the problem.
After failing with the graphical installer yesterday, today i used the text installer.
For partitioning my two SSDs, folowing worked for me in manual mode, first SSD (128 GB)

1. creating a 1 GB EFI partition
2. creating a 3 GB /boot partition
3. use the rest of the first SSD as encrypted space (configure encrypted volumes)
4. create a volume group i the encrypted space (configure logical volume manager)
5. create a logical volume in this volume group
6. create a partition in this logical volume an use it as /

second SSD (1 TB):

1. use complete space as encrypted space (configure encrypted volumes)
2. create a second volume group on this SSD (configure logical volume manager)
3. create two logical volumes (on for /home, one as SWAP) in this volume group
4. create a patition in both logical volumes an use them as /home and SWAP

That's it